# EVGA Precision X doesn't have Automatic Profile managment

Tags: nvidia-geforce, overclocking, underclock

I have installed the last version of EVGA Precision X: 4.2.1

But in the Profiles tab there isn't anymore the Section to manage 2d/3d profiles:

[image]

That was pretty useful as it let me to rise the clocks while playing. Any way to manage 2d/3d profiles automatically?

I have a Geforce GTX 260 with Windows 8

**Update:** Solved by using MSI Afterburner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since version 4.1 the server isn't part of the client-installation. So the server-dependent functionalities are hidden.

You have to install the server manually.

Excerpt from the 4.1 changelog:

> The server is no longer being distributed as a part of client
>   applications like EVGA Precision. Now it comes with own installer and
>   can be optionally installed when necessary. **EVGA Precision will
>   automatically hide any server dependent functionality** (such as
>   On-Screen Display, framerate monitoring, **automatic 2D/3D profiles
>   management**, screen capture and so on) when the server is not installed

[Complete Changelog](http://geeteck.net/tech-news/evga-precision-x-4-2-1-released/)

Comment: I have switched to MSI Afterburner is working much better without having to install other things